# Can we skip using instance variables to render JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

If there's no need to use an instance variable, is there any benefits or drawback doing so ? Can I use one liner inside controller's actions ?

```rb
def index
  render Foo.all
end
```

If routes are wraped inside `contraints format: :json { ... }`, Rails renders data formatted as expected and I don't see the need of using an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, an instance variable that is not strictly necessary can be used to document or split up complex 1-liners. In this case, the relative simplicity does not warrant this adjustment - your code is fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks for noticing documentation, I haven't thought about it. You're also right, we all prefer a well-named variable to a complex 1 liners